# What do `def +@` and `def -@` mean?

Tags: ruby

In this [Haskell-like comprehensions implementation in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/andkerosine/3356675#file-raskell-rb) there's some code I've never seen in Ruby:

```
class Array
  def +@
    # implementation
  end

  def -@
    # implementation
  end
end
```

What do `def +@` and `def -@` mean? Where to find (semi-)official informations about them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are unary `+` and `-` methods. They are called when you write `-object` or `+object`. The syntax `+x`, for example, is replaced with `x.+@`.

Consider this:

```
class Foo
  def +(other_foo)
    puts 'binary +'
  end

  def +@
    puts 'unary +'
  end
end

f = Foo.new
g = Foo.new

+ f   
# unary +

f + g 
# binary +

f + (+ g) 
# unary +
# binary +
```

Another less contrived example:

```
class Array
  def -@
    map(&:-@)
  end
end

- [1, 2, -3]
# => [-1, -2, 3]
```

They are mentioned [here](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#operatorexpressions) and there's an article about how to define them [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html).

Comment: `[]+[]` or `[]+([])` after that definition does not return an error.

Comment: @sawa: That's because `Array` already comes with a binary `+` method.

Comment: If `Array#+` is overridden as a unary method, then it should return an error when an argument is passed.

Comment: That's not `Array#+` it is `Array#+@`.

Comment: Then, that is not an explanation. The question was asking what `Array#+@` is, and if you just say it is not `Array#+` but is `Array#+@`, you are just repeating the question. Telling how they differ is the whole point of the question. If you say it is a unary method, it can mean something being used like `[:foo]+()`. However, with you added example, it became clear now.